# How to fix/prevent overlapping of <body> to <footer>?

Tags: html, css

I have tried Position:fixed/static/relative/absolute... still overlapping on the body & sometimes the footer(blocking other parts of the body).

Image:[image: Overlapped Body on the footer section]

```css
/* Footer */

footer {
  background: #444;
}

.h-sec {
  font: 22px Arial, Helvetica;
}

.sec {
  font: 9px, Arial, Helvetica;
}

#f-nav a {
  color: #F4F4F4;
}

#f-nav .current {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.a-void {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <section class="f-sec1">
    <h5>CAD | Tech Website&copy;</h5>

    <br>
    <div id="f-nav">
      <a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
      <a href="services.html">Services</a>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      <a href="about.html">About us</a>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section>
    <a href="####.com" class="a-void">Donate :)</a>
  </section>
</footer>
```

for the full code(Error in images): https://jsfiddle.net/s0nk37cg/ - ***IT WILL LOOK FINE BUT IT IS BECAUSE THERE IS NO IMAGE, PLEASE LOOK AT THE IMAGE OR MAKE YOU OWN IMAGE TO BE CLEAR AND UNDERSTANDABLE***

Comment: you need to clear the floats. see https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ :)  `clear:both;`

Comment: What floats? The question needs to include a [mcve]

Comment: Please don't ask part of your question in bold and caps. Also, simply setting the footer to position static or fixed or relative or absolute won't solve any problems on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Step 1** - Add the below to your css:

```
.clearfix:after {content:""; display:table; clear:both;}
```

**Step 2** - Changes in your html:
Change:

```
    <section id="container" >
```

- to -

```
     <section id="container" class="clearfix">
```

see if that help, you might have to tweek your margins and/or padding though

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix for this problem is to give a margin-bottom value to your body element to avoid overlap at the end of the page or scroll. provide the value depending on the height of your footer.

Comment: Here are a few things I updated. 
Inline style for body margin-bottom (since it was not being applied using external css in the fiddle)
Position, width, top and bottom values for the footer element. 

https://jsfiddle.net/s0nk37cg/1/